# When POST'ing Dropdowns values, only first value gets posted, second is null (using JSCRIPT, PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, drop-down-menu

EDIT: My main code no longer works, should this function work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script>
var second_choice = $('#second-choice').val();
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
$("$second-choice").load("findModel.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
</script>
```

Here is the associated PHP File:

```
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
$choice = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['choice']);

$query="SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `DVLAMake`='$choice'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option>" . $row{'DVLAModel'} . "</option>";
}
?>
```

The database connection works.

#

On load a PHP file populates my first dropdown:

```
<form name="indexSearch" action="searchResults.php" method="POST">

<select id="first-choice">
<option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
<option value="VAUXHALL">VAUXHALL</option>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT `DVLAMake` FROM `cars`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo "<option value =\"{$data[DVLAMake]}\" >{$data[DVLAMake]}</option>\n";
} 
?>
</select>

<select id="second-choice">
<option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>
<br />

<input type="submit" style="font-size:14px; padding:3;"value="Submit" size="20" />
</form>
```

That works, and then on choosing the value it calls a function which then fills the second with options which I can choose from. However when I post the form, it doesn't take the second dropdown selected value through it's just empty but it does take the first dropdown value selected value.

Any reason why?

Comment: You dont have `name` attribute for your select input

Comment: You have no form controls with a `name` attribute, that shouldn't be able to submit *any* data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second select tag does not have name attribute. if it lies in the form you will get the request via post only if the attribute has name. if you are using jquery you can simply fetch value by id then post it via ajax. select like this in jquery.

```
var second_choice = $('#second-choice').val();
```

Comment: actually - none of the <select> tags have name attributes

Comment: Turns out my code isn't working anymore. Forget the original question; my first dropdown populates, but when I change the second nothing happens. 

My jquery function is just at the top near the head function, is that correct:


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
   
<script>
var second_choice = $('#second-choice').val();
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
 $("$second-choice").load("findModel.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the selected value? Using e.g. ajax? And how are you sending your data? Using ajax or simple POST with page reload?

If you're changing something using ajax your data need to be send by ajax. Because without it you will don't send your data generated by JS but this generated by your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
$("$second-choice").load("findModel.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
```

instead of:

```
$("#second-choice").load("findModel.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
```

**$** -> **#**